# Qliksense Javascript Extensions

Tags: javascript, qliksense

I'm trying to learn more how extensions can be built with JavaScript on the Qlik platform. I was told to start with Qlik Sense since it is easier. Can anyone provide any insight please? Are any other technologies used, etc? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Building Qlik Sense extensions is easier than QlikView (in my opinion). You'll need JS/HTML/CSS skills

You can start by reading [Qlik Sense documentation](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/3.1/Subsystems/Extensions/Content/extensions-introduction.htm) or follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/stefanwalther/qliksense-extension-tutorial) (for example) also you can take a look at [Qlik Branch](http://branch.qlik.com/#!/project) and check the code behind the ready extensions there.